# How to stop Solr delta import from creating a log file

Tags: solr

I have solr installed on Debian and every time delta import takes place a file gets created in my root directory.
The files look like this

```
  dataimport?command=delta-import.1
  dataimport?command=delta-import.2
  .
  .
  .
  dataimport?command=delta-import.30
```

Every time there is a delta import a file gets created , i opened the file in vi editor and its an xml file.
Why are these files getting created and how do i stop solr from creating them.

To start solr i use this command

```
  Java -jar start.jar &
```

According to this command no log files should be created.
Please advise and help iam new to solr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are generated by the command invoking the delta-import. From the file name it seems you have a cronjob running that does a `wget ..` on the URL, which results in wget attempting to create a file named `dataimport?command=delta-import` in the directory where it's running. When that file exists, it appends `.1` and up.

Check which command you run from cron (`crontab -e`) and if you're using wget, append `-O /dev/null` to your command to make wget discard the response from the server.

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh for the response you are absolutely correct iam using wget
It looks like this
0 * * * * wget --quiet 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8983/solr/dataimport?command=delta-import'
What do i change in this to stop it from creating those files.

Comment: Hi MatsLindh i tried it but it not working.Am i doing something wrong
This is what my cron job looks like
0 * * * * wget --quiet -o /dev/null 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8983/solr/dataimport?command=delta-import'
The files are still being created 
Please advise